# Why isn't isEmpty in Kotlin Collections a property?

Tags: kotlin

I'm starting to learn Kotlin, and just noticed that `Collections.isEmpty` is a function, rather than a property. However, `Collections.size` is a property and not a function.

In most (all?) collections, I expect these two to be related semantically, and the implementation of `isEmpty` can simply be `size === 0`.

So... why isn't `isEmpty` a property? Is it simply a design bug?

Comment: Could it have something to do with the fact that there is an `isNotEmpty()` extension function for `Collections` that returns `!isEmpty()`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When deciding which methods of `java.util.Collection` will be properties in `kotlin.collections.Collection` the following considerations were taken into account:

- both `size` and `isEmpty` can be qualified as properties according to [Kotlin coding conventions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#functions-vs-properties), however `size` is inherent to the collection and `isEmpty` is just a derivative of the `size` property.
- when implementing a collection one can override `size` *val* property with a *var* property (likely with a private setter), however the same is hardly ever needed for `isEmpty`.
- exposing a method as a property requires additional methods generated in derived classes, better to keep their number as small as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't understand your second point though. A method can just as easily be overriden as well can't it?

Comment: @Ginandi a method `size()` can obviously be overriden as well, however to implement it you likely have to introduce a backing property, `_size`. By overriding `val size` with `var size` (with private setter), you get both an override of getter and a backing field to store the value.

Answer (score 0):

In java you have the `list.isEmpty()` method [List#isEmpty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#isEmpty()).
Having a `list.isNotEmpty` property in kotlin would confuse people.

IMHO the reason why the Kotlin-Devs choose to make `isNotEmpty` a method rather than a property is consistency with java.